# How to create a 3D spinning effect using SVGs

Tags: svg

I have a question about animating SVGs.  I was given a 3D movie clip of a spinning token that changes color to try to recreate using SVGs.  I tried using an animated radialGradient tag in the defs, but it doesn’t look the same, since in the movie, the colors wrap around in a parabola shape, but when I use radialGradient, it just looks like a circle of color moving across the token image.
Does anyone with SVG experience have any ideas on how to best accomplish this?  Is it possible to accomplish using different fill gradients?  Or do I need to look into using something like three.js?  Or should I try to embed the movie clip?  I really appreciate any feedback!
Movie clip I’m trying to replicate:  https://trello-attachments.s3.amazonaws.com/5a8b15437a02ee5d87991772/5b1aa52382aa1411afffc12c/fb7d36d4c45dfda665b9d0ee46231b8a/DIwala_Token_(Converted)_Test.m4v
My attempt using SVG radialGradient: https://github.com/SashaBajzek/diwala-frontpage-firebase/blob/fe08ea16f2885fb78846212fabfb3bda41863595/src/components/animated_token/AnimatedToken.tsx

```
import * as React from 'react';

export default function AnimatedToken(props: any) {
    return(
        <svg viewBox="0 0 700 666" className="AnimatedToken">
            <defs>
                <radialGradient id="smallGradient" fx="50%" fy="50%">
                    <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#FFDE7E"/>
                    <stop offset="75%" stop-color="#BC41B0"/>
                    <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#7C07C9"/>
                    <animate attributeName="fx" dur="10s" from="100%" to="0%" repeatCount="indefinite" />
                </radialGradient>
            </defs>
            <g>
                <g>
                    <path fill="url(#smallGradient)" d="M337,1c8.7,0,17.3,0,26,0c2.4,0.5,4.9,1,7.3,1.4c31.6,5.3,60.3,18.1,87.2,34.8c64.9,40.2,122.7,88.9,172,147.3
          c25.4,30.1,46,63.2,60.8,100c11,27.3,12.8,54.4,3.7,82.5c-6.4,19.8-15,38.5-25.6,56.3c-17.7,29.8-39.2,56.7-62.3,82.4
          c-31.2,34.6-63.9,67.5-102.4,94.1c-24,16.6-48.3,32.7-74.5,45.8c-21.6,10.8-44.1,18.7-68.3,21.4c-5.3,0-10.7,0-16,0
          c-8.8-1.7-17.8-2.9-26.4-5.3c-37.4-10.4-70.9-28.9-102.5-50.8c-54.6-37.8-102.5-83-144.5-134.2C38.5,436.5,9.6,394,1,341
          c0-7.7,0-15.3,0-23c0.8-3.2,1.5-6.5,2.3-9.7c8.8-35.2,26.4-66.1,47.9-94.8c42.1-56.3,92.3-104.6,148.3-146.8
          C240.8,35.5,284.9,9.7,337,1z"/>
                </g>
            </g>
        </svg>
    );
}
```

Comment: Please post the code using `code block` and don't just link it.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know about code block!  This is my first stack overflow experience.